# Sharepoint databases status in SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

We have a SharePoint oriented environment where all the content and config databases are hosted on SQL Server. My question is there some way from SQL Server end to find out if the content databases are attached to SharePoint CA?
The only way I know to find this info is to log into the server and run the **Get-SPDatabase** command to get all the databases attached to the CA. Can this somehow be achieved from backend? By using SQL Queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a rough way to see which database is in use running the query [sp_who](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) which outputs (among other things) loginame, hostname and dbname. You will find the connections to all databases in this sql server instance.

If you save the query to a file, you can easily import it to excel to filter its content.

Comment: Is this the only way to get this? Also the results using this will be same as the one with we get using Get-SPDatabase??

Comment: @user2068804 From SQL Server you could use the profiler tool as well, but it needs heavy filtering. And it's not the same as Get-SPDatabase which will output all the databases in one time. sp_who outputs connections, and you usually have more than one connection to each database.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be querying SharePoint databases directly, no matter what data you want to get.

More info: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665755/how-do-i-query-the-sharepoint-database) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_farnhill/archive/2013/12/04/directly-querying-sharepoint-databases.aspx)

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the query I'm asking for wil just be a select query. I don't think that will have any harm. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @user2068804 even select queries is unsupported actually